# Removing unwanted Observation, and calculating Time Difference

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, reshape2

I have a data frame, when an id is audited it can be either Passed or failed at that particular time. how to calculate, the sum of all the time taken to change status from Failed to Passed state w.r.t id's. If an id has failed, failed, Passed state. I have to add time taken to change status from first failed to passed and second failed to passed state

```
time <- c("08-10-2018 08:36", "12-10-2018 07:53", "23-10-2018 23:09", "30-10-2018 18:24","07-11-2018 18:13","10-11-2018 05:47","19-11-2018 21:26","26-11-2018 14:04","16-10-2018 03:19","07-11-2018 19:00","09-11-2018 23:25","20-11-2018 19:24", "22-11-2018 01:12","28-11-2018 03:46","04-10-2018 15:05","15-10-2018 15:32","20-10-2018 06:21","26-10-2018 04:51","02-11-2018 00:28","09-11-2018 22:43","15-11-2018 22:39","21-11-2018 04:10","26-11-2018 13:29")
id <-c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3")
status <- c("FAILED","PASSED","FAILED","PASSED","FAILED","PASSED","PASSED","PASSED","PASSED","FAILED","PASSED","FAILED","PASSED","PASSED","PASSED","FAILED","PASSED","PASSED","PASSED","FAILED","PASSED","PASSED","FAILED")

df <- data.frame(id, time, status)
```

Required Format:

```
ids <- c("A1","A2", "A3")
diff_time <- c(13.25, 3.46, 10.61)
df2 <- data.frame(ids,diff_time)
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: But you have several transitions from Failed -> Passed for each Id. How come you only have 1 value for each?

Comment: You need to elaborate more. This is not a coding service, you need to help us to help you. Provide more details like how `diff_time` is being calculated

Comment: I have a data frame, when an id is audited it can be either Passed or failed at that particular time.
how to calculate, the sum of all the time taken to change status from Failed to Passed state w.r.t id's. If an id has failed, failed, Passed state. I have to add time taken to change status from first failed to passed and second failed to passed state.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to measure the time difference between each `FAILED` event to the next subsequent `PASSED` event (for each `id`). Finally, the measured differences need to be summed up for each `id`.

This can be solved by a *backward rolling join* which is available with the `data.table` package.

First, we have to separate the `FAILED` and `PASSED` events. Then, a *right join* is used in order to find a subsequent `PASSED` event for each `FAILED` event. The two subsets are joined on `id` and `time` where the time is rolled backward (NOCB = next observation carried backwards).

```
library(data.table)
# coerce df to data.table, coerce time to POSIXct
setDT(df)[, time := lubridate::dmy_hm(time)]
# create subset PASSED
dfp <- df[status == "PASSED"][, timep := time]
# create subset FAILED
dff <- df[status == "FAILED"][, timef := time]
# backward rolling join
dfp[dff, on = .(id, time),  roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>    id                time status               timep i.status               timef
> 1: A1 2018-10-08 08:36:00 PASSED 2018-10-12 07:53:00   FAILED 2018-10-08 08:36:00
> 2: A1 2018-10-23 23:09:00 PASSED 2018-10-30 18:24:00   FAILED 2018-10-23 23:09:00
> 3: A1 2018-11-07 18:13:00 PASSED 2018-11-10 05:47:00   FAILED 2018-11-07 18:13:00
> 4: A2 2018-11-07 19:00:00 PASSED 2018-11-09 23:25:00   FAILED 2018-11-07 19:00:00
> 5: A2 2018-11-20 19:24:00 PASSED 2018-11-22 01:12:00   FAILED 2018-11-20 19:24:00
> 6: A3 2018-10-15 15:32:00 PASSED 2018-10-20 06:21:00   FAILED 2018-10-15 15:32:00
> 7: A3 2018-11-09 22:43:00 PASSED 2018-11-15 22:39:00   FAILED 2018-11-09 22:43:00
> 8: A3 2018-11-26 13:29:00   <NA>                <NA>   FAILED 2018-11-26 13:29:00
> ```

```
# rolling join and aggregate by id
dfp[dff, on = .(id, time),  roll = -Inf][, .(diff_time = sum(timep - timef, na.rm = TRUE)), by = id]
```

> ```
>    id      diff_time
> 1: A1 13.254167 days
> 2: A2  3.425694 days
> 3: A3 10.614583 days
> ```